# Checkbox array returning NULL

Tags: php, html

I want a batch deletion feature in the billing system I am developing, however the checkboxes, when `var_dump`ed yields a NULL value **when checked**.

Here is my markup **(edited)**:

```
<form method="post" name="form-countries-del">
<div id="deleteBox">
    <span class="middleAlign"><b>No. of Records:</b> <span class="red"><?= $qtotal; ?></span></span>
    <span class="rightAlign">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="submit-countries-del" class="del-submit" />
    </span>
</div>
<table border="1" id="src-table">
    <tr class="header">
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="toggleChecks"></td>
        <td class="_hide">CountryID</td>
        <td>Country Code</td>
        <td>Country Name</td>
        <td>Telco Rate</td>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row = $pdo->fetch()) : ?>
    <tr class="<?=($c++%2==1) ? 'even' : 'odd' ?>" title="Double click to edit">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="toDelete[]" id="toDelete[]" class="toDelete" value="<?= $row['CountryID']; ?>" /></td>
        <td class="_hide"><?= $row['CountryID']; ?></td>
        <td><?= highlight($_POST['search'], $row['CountryCode']); ?></td>
        <td><?= highlight($_POST['search'], $row['CountryName']); ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['Trate']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
</form>
```

The generated form (Google Chrome) is like this:
[image: Form generation code] 
It just yields NULL unfortunately. I wonder what I've been missing. I've been scanning a whole lot of similar articles regarding my problem but none has worked thus far.

I hope you folks can help me!
Cheers!

Comment: Does your `form` closed correctly? check with inspect element from your browser

Comment: It is closed correctly.

Comment: Can you show of your form?

Comment: Should I take a screenshot of the element console?

Comment: I just checked on it. It seems Chrome meddles with my code. It closed my form tag before it even scoped the checkboxes. Interestingly, if that were the case, why would var_dump print toDelete as NULL?

Comment: Of course, Nothing in the post it will setted as NULL ..

Comment: show us the vardump of $_POST after submitting

Comment: array(2) { ["submit-countries-del"]=> string(6) "Delete" ["toDelete"]=> NULL }

Comment: and (though a far shot) , remove `id="toDelete[]"`, as it isn't proper to have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: Just as I thought. Haha.

Comment: @JellyAce show us more code please. show us from the beginning to the part that you do the var_dump. I'm wondering if you are overwriting that value

Comment: I don't think those things have something to do with my problem. I'm using MVC-like style coding.

Comment: @JellyAce still I think it's quite possible you are overwriting `$_POST['toDelete']` by accident in your code. Maybe some silly mistake like `if($_POST['toDelete'] = null)` , where `=` should be `==`

Comment: I don't have that kind of code.

Answer (score 0):

Until you check the checkbox you will get the value as NULL, Once you checked the checkbox and try with post method you will retrieve the value.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did it. :)

Comment: Of course it is not. No reason to downvote his answer though.

Comment: The value won't be `NULL`, it won't be set at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have bad html.

Move the `<form method="post" name="form-countries-del">` to before `<div id="deleteBox">`

Comment: This. This is what I've been thinking for hours but didn't have the interest to try. Haha.

Comment: Just `var_dump($_POST);` without any conditions and see what you get

Comment: Forgot to tell you that. Yea, submit-countries-del is there.

Comment: Can you append your question with the generated HTML rather than the php

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` close`(</form>)` not defined in properly.

Your html code will generate like this, `<span> <form>  ......(without ending form) </span>`

The Html parse the If any unclosed tags presents it will automatically added closing tag inbetween.

like this,

```
<span >
    <form>
        <!-- Submit button -->
    </form>    <!-- added automatically -->

</span>

<!-- Check box elements goes here -->
```

Comment: I changed my HTML code already. Nothing good happened though.

Comment: @JellyAce : Show your html form

Comment: Can you see what's actually being posted in the network tab (click preserve log)

Comment: @AndyGee, is it for me?

Comment: In chrome click inspect element, then click the network tab and select "preserve log". Clear the log (no entry symbol) submit the form. You may see many requests, look for the POST request, right click it and copy the request headers. This will show you what actually was sent. Paste it here.

Comment: It is for me @Ranjith.

Comment: @JellyAce please right click the request and select "copy request headers". Screenshots are not helpful. Add the request headers to your question.

Comment: @JellyAce Possible answer: Some MVC frameworks remove the POST data (that's just one of the many reasons I hate all PHP MVC frameworks)

Comment: @AndyGee the variable isn't removed. It is null. And the submit-variable is also not removed and still has its value.

Comment: Something is making it null though. Have you tried `name="toDelete-<?= $row['CountryID']; ?>"`

Comment: I'm not using any MVC frameworks. I just patterned my coding style to one, and yes, I tried what you have suggested. It works. It's just the checkboxes being an array that makes it produce wrong output. I wonder why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Some MVC frameworks mess around with the request variables such as POST. It's possible this is the case with you. As your submit button is posting ok, it could be just a problem with POSTing arrays. Try this to get around that problem.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="toDelete-<?= $row['CountryID']; ?>" id="toDelete[]" class="toDelete" value="<?= $row['CountryID']; ?>" /></td>
        <td class="_hide"><?= $row['CountryID']; ?>
```

You can access the values like so:

```
$toDelete = array();
foreach($_POST as $p){
    $ex = explode('-',$p);
    if($ex[0]=='toDelete'){
        $toDelete[] = $ex[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this will do the trick. However, I'm not sure on how can I implement batch deletion with such names.