# some of the fields shows null value in var_dump for $_POST

Tags: php, html, post, smarty

I am trying to troubleshoot a from html, PHP. the frontend template is in smarty.

When I am doing a `var_dump($_POST)` some of the values in the form like checkbox, shows `null` value`

but when I am using `var_dump($_REQUEST)` It comes up correctly.

The form is set as `method=post`.

Besides If I am copying the whole html from the browser and checking it on my localhost, `var_dump($_POST)` is showing the values correctly.

so what could be the reason of missing values when using `$_POST`, not able to make it out?

The contents of the file update_profile.tpl is like this:

Attached code is stripped version for space limit;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="big-left">
    <div class="btop-data-left">
        <h2>Update Profile</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    {if $successMsg != ''}
        <div class="success">{$successMsg}</div>
    {/if}
    <br/>
</div>
{if $flagUpdate}
    <div style="float:right;">
    <!--<a href="{$Site_Root}tutor_profile_admin.php?tutor_id={$tutorData->tutor_id}">View Profile</a>-->
    {if $backPage=='tutProf'}
        <a href="{$Site_Root}tutor_profile_admin.php?tutor_id={$tutorData->tutor_id}">&laquo; Back</a>
    {/if}
    {if $backPage=='tutSear'}
        <a href="{$Site_Root}admin_advance_search.php">&laquo; Back</a>
    {/if}
    </div>
    {/if}
<form action="" method="post" class="frmRegister" name="frmRegister" id="frmRegister" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div class="tutor-registration">
        <div class="ttr-rg-title"> Personal Particulars & Contacts Details <span>(this field is compulsory)</span> </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="tutor-registration-form">


            <div class="tab-content" id="level">
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                    {section name=rec loop=$levelCount}
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top"  style="padding-bottom: 15px;"><input type="checkbox" name="ls[]" id="selectAll{$smarty.section.rec.iteration}"><b>{$level_name[rec]}</b>
                            <br />
                                {section name=rec1 loop=$subCount[rec]}
                                {assign var="k" value="$level_id[rec]"}

                                <input type="checkbox" value="{$subject_id[rec][rec1]}" name="level_subject[{$level_id[rec]}][]" {if $subject_id[rec][rec1]|in_array:$level_subject.$k}checked{/if} class="{$level_id[rec]}{$smarty.section.rec.iteration}"/>
                                <font class="bodytext">{$subject_name[rec][rec1]}</font>
                                {/section}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {literal}
                        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                $('#selectAll{/literal}{$smarty.section.rec.iteration}{literal}').click(function(event) {  //on click
                                    if(this.checked) { // check select status
                                        $('.{/literal}{$level_id[rec]}{$smarty.section.rec.iteration}{literal}').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                                            this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"
                                        });
                                    }else{
                                        $('.{/literal}{$level_id[rec]}{$smarty.section.rec.iteration}{literal}').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                                            this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"
                                        });
                                    }
                                });

                            });
                        </script>
                        {/literal}
                    {/section}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content" id="experience">
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="60%" valign="top"><font class="bodytext">
                            You are encouraged to write a short description of yourself, teaching experience and teaching method. If you are teaching or have taught in any school/institution, you are advise to include the same name of the school/institution you teaching/taught in, and the level/s and subject/s you teaching there. You can always log in to edit this later.<br>
                                <br><b>Example:</b> <i>I have one year experience teaching a primary 5 and secondary 2.</i> or <i>After giving tuition to a sec 3 girl, her grades have improved from B3 to A1.</i></font><br>
                                <br>
                                <textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="experience">{$tutorData->experience}</textarea>
                            </td>
                            <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td valign="top"> Years of Experience<br>
                                <select name="year_experience">
                                                      <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '0'} selected="true" {/if} value="0">0</option>
                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '1'} selected="true" {/if} value="1">1</option>
                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '2'} selected="true" {/if} value="2">2</option>
                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '3'} selected="true" {/if} value="3">3</option>
                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '4'} selected="true" {/if} value="4">4</option>
                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '5'} selected="true" {/if} value="5">5</option>
                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '6'} selected="true" {/if} value="6">6</option>
                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '7'} selected="true" {/if} value="7">7</option>
                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '8'} selected="true" {/if} value="8">8</option>
                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '9'} selected="true" {/if} value="9">9</option>
                                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '10'} selected="true" {/if} value="10">10</option>
                                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '11'} selected="true" {/if} value="11">11</option>
                                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '12'} selected="true" {/if} value="12">12</option>
                                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '13'} selected="true" {/if} value="13">13</option>
                                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '14'} selected="true" {/if} value="14">14</option>
                                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '15'} selected="true" {/if} value="15">15</option>
                                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '16'} selected="true" {/if} value="16">16</option>
                                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '17'} selected="true" {/if} value="17">17</option>
                                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '18'} selected="true" {/if} value="18">18</option>
                                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '19'} selected="true" {/if} value="19">19</option>
                                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '20'} selected="true" {/if} value="20">20</option>
                                    <option {if $tutorData->year_experience == '20+'} selected="true" {/if} value="20+">More than 20</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="result[]" maxlength="50" value="{$result[langdet]}" />
                            </td>
                            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="tr_{$lgid[langdet]}" onclick='javascript: $(this).parent().parent().remove();'><img src="{$Templates_Image}remove.png" alt="" /></a> </td>
                        </tr>
                       {/section}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="hidden" name="lgcnt" value="{$langCount}">
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0" class="languages" style="display:none;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="17%">
                                <select id="language_code" name="language_code[]">
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            {$languageList}
                                        </select>
                            </td>
                            <td width="10%">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="primary_flag[]" onchange="javascript: checkUncheckLang(this);">
                                <input type="hidden" name="primary_flag_hidden[]" value="0">
                             </td>
                            <td width="10%">
                                <select id="spoken_level" name="spoken_level[]">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                        <option value="9">9</option>
                                        <option value="8">8</option>
                                        <option value="7">7</option>
                                        <option value="6">6</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="0">0</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td width="10%">
                                <select id="written_level" name="written_level[]">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                        <option value="9">9</option>
                                        <option value="8">8</option>
                                        <option value="7">7</option>
                                        <option value="6">6</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="0">0</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td width="25%">
                                <select id="certificate_code" name="certificate_code[]">
                                    <option value="">- Select Certificate -</option>
                                    {$certiList}
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td width="15%">
                                <input type="text" name="result[]" maxlength="50" />
                            </td>
                            <td width="13%"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='javascript: $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();'><img src="{$Templates_Image}remove.png" alt="" /></a> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                </div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-lang" onclick='javascript: $( ".languages" ).clone().appendTo( ".languageList" ).show().removeClass("languages");'><img src="{$Templates_Image}pls.png">Add Language</a>
                 <!--<br /><br /><strong>Tuition Jobs Portal English Language Assessment - <a href="#">Help</a> </strong>-->
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content tabresults" id="skillsmusic">
                <div class="skillList">
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="18%"><u>Skills/Music</u></td>
                            <td width="13%"><u>Proficiency</u></td>
                            <td width="22%"><u>Relevant Certificates (Optional)</u></td>
                            <td width="47%"><u></u></td>
                        </tr>
                         {section name=skilldet loop=$skillCount}
                        <tr id="tr_{$skid[skillCount]}">
                            <td><input type="text" name="skill[]" id="skillsnmusic" value="{$skill[skilldet]}" onfocus="javascript: $(this).siblings('.resumeTips').show();" onblur="javascript: $(this).siblings('.resumeTips').hide();"/>
                            <div id="resumeTips" class="colLeft resumeTips -hide" style="display: none;">
                                <div id="tip-skills" class="tips tooltips">
                                    <div id="lbl-tip-skill" class="tipsSentence">Enter your skills (e.g. Project Management, Cost Accounting, C++, Oracle8).</div>
                                    <div class="up-arrow-border"></div>
                                    <div class="up-arrow"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><select name="proficiency[]" id="proficiency">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    {$proficiency[skilldet]}
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="certy[]" id="certy" value="{$certivalue[skilldet]}"/></td>
                            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="tr_{$skid[skillCount]}" onclick='javascript: $(this).parent().parent().remove();'><img src="{$Templates_Image}remove.png" alt="" /></a> </td>
                        </tr>
                        {/section}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                     <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0" class="skills" style="display:none;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="18%"><input type="text" name="skill[]" id="skillsnmusic" onfocus="javascript: $(this).siblings('.resumeTips').show();" onblur="javascript: $(this).siblings('.resumeTips').hide();"/>
                            <div id="resumeTips" class="resumeTips" style="display: none;">
                                <div id="tip-skills" class="tips tooltips">
                                    <div id="lbl-tip-skill" class="tipsSentence">Enter your skills (e.g. Project Management, Cost Accounting, C++, Oracle8).</div>
                                    <div class="up-arrow-border"></div>
                                    <div class="up-arrow"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="13%"><select name="proficiency[]" id="proficiency">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    {$proficiencyList}
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td width="22%"><input type="text" name="certy[]" id="certy" /></td>
                            <td width="47%"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='javascript: $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();'><img src="{$Templates_Image}remove.png" alt="" /></a> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
                <div id="resumeTips" class="colLeft resumeTips -hide" style="display: none;">
                    <div id="tip-skills" class="tips tooltips">
                        <div id="lbl-tip-skill" class="tipsSentence">Enter your skills (e.g. Project Management, Cost Accounting, C++, Oracle8).</div>
                        <div class="up-arrow-border"></div>
                        <div class="up-arrow"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-lang" onclick='javascript: $( ".skills" ).clone().appendTo( ".skillList" ).show().removeClass("skills");'><img src="{$Templates_Image}pls.png">Add Skill / Music</a> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ttr-rg-title"> Upload Photo </div>
        <div class="upload-photo-rg">
            <div class="upload-thumb"> <span>Current Photo</span> <img src="{$img_path}small_thumb_{$tutorData->photo}"> </div>
            <div class="upload-photo-data"> <b>Upload a Photo</b>
                <p>You can Upload a JPG, GIF or PNG file (File size limit is 4MB).</p>
                <input type="file" name="photo"  /><br><i>Please upload photo having minimum dimensions 120px X 140px (Width X Height).</i>
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_photo" value="{$tutorData->photo}" />
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <p>We highly recommend you to upload your photo to increase your chance of getting assignments. If you do not have your photo ready, you can upload it later. Please upload only your personal photo.</p>
        </div>
       {if $flagUpdate}
       <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="ttr-rg-title"> Resume Privacy Setting </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="bigtab-data">
            <ul class="priority-app-list">
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="searchable" value="1" {if $tutorData->searchable=="1"}checked{/if} />
                    <div class="pal-data"> <b>Searchable with Contact Details </b>
                        <p> Allow Employers to search for my resume and see my name and contact details.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="searchable" value="0" {if $tutorData->searchable=="0"}checked{/if} />
                    <div class="pal-data"> <b>Not Searchable</b>
                        <p>Do not allow employers to search for my resume.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="ttr-rg-title"> Profile Notification </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="bigtab-data">
            <ul class="priority-app-list">
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="profile_notification" value="1" {if $tutorData->profile_notification=="1"}checked{/if} />
                    <div class="pal-data"> <b>Receive Notification of Tuition Jobs via Text Messages </b>
                        <p> This enables you to get your preferred tuition jobs faster</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="profile_notification" value="0" {if $tutorData->profile_notification=="0"}checked{/if} />
                    <div class="pal-data"> <b>Do not like to Receive Notification of Tuition Jobs via Text Messages</b>
                        <p>You will only get notification via emails or phone calls.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        {/if}
    </div>



    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="tutor-registration-form" style="width:100%; text-align:center;"> <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="tutor_id" value="{$tutorData->tutor_id}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="flagUpdate" value="{$flagUpdate}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="from" value="{$backPage}" />
        <button type="submit" class="c-profile" name="submit" value="Update Profile" >Update Profile</button>
        <hr>
    </div>
</form>
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tabresults1').tabify();
        $('#tabresults').tabify();
    });

    // JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#Loading_1').hide();
    $('#Loading_2').hide();
    $('#Loading_3').hide();
    $('#loader_1').hide();

    /*$('.languageList input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e){
        if($(this).prop('checked'))
        { alert('1');
            $(this).next().val(1);
        } else {
            $(this).next().val(0);
        }
    });*/
});

function checkUncheckLang(th)
{
  if($(th).prop('checked'))
  {
      $(th).next().val(1);
  } else {
      $(th).next().val(0);
  }
}

function checkUserEmail(value,rec){
 //alert(val);
    var username = $(value).val();

    if(username.length > 0){
        $('#Loading_'+rec).show();
        $.get(""+site_root+"check_availability.php", {
            username: username,
        }, function(response){
            $('#Info_'+rec).fadeOut();
             $('#Loading_'+rec).hide();
             var responseArray  =   response.split('###');
             if(responseArray[1] == '0')
             {
                 value.value='';
             }
            setTimeout("finishAjax('Info_"+rec+"', '"+escape(responseArray[0])+"')", 450);
        });
        return false;
    }
}
function finishAjax(id, response){
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn(1000);
}

$(function() {
    //$( "#birthdate" ).datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, maxDate: "-18Y", dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
    $('#birthdate').combodate();
});

</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: unchecked checkboxes always return null.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use loops for generating options in select, for instance:

```
{foreach from=$arrNetworkDTO item=NetworkDTO}
    <option value="{$NetworkDTO->name|escape}">{$NetworkDTO->name}</option>
{/foreach}
```

About null values somebody also had that problem: [Checkbox array returning NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011467/checkbox-array-returning-null)

Comment: useful as this maybe, this is not an answer to the question